# Red hand on a lot of transactions

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

We suddenly have a lot of red hands in "Open vendor transactions". We had weird problems due to a lack of database maintenance plan, now the system is up and running, but too many red hands are showing.

I saw this on MS: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/894412

But this is not very practical as it's not one offending record, but many.

Is there any way to spot marked transactions that should not be, quickly, in transact SQL ?

Is finding orphans in **SpecTrans** VS **VendTransOpen** a good start ?

Thanks!

EDIT: Thinking of it, finding orphaned records in SpecTrans probably won't help as a red hand probably means the transaction *was* found in SpecTrans...

EDIT#2: I found [this](http://dynamicsuser.net/forums/p/61451/327950.aspx#327950) to unmark certain transactions, but when I do what is being proposed, I cannot find any associated journal. This might be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After backing up the table, this is what I ended up doing:

```
delete from SPECTRANS where SPECTRANS.RECID in
(
     select st.RECID from VENDTRANS vt
     inner join VENDTRANSOPEN vto on vto.REFRECID = vt.RECID
     inner join SPECTRANS st on st.REFRECID = vto.RECID
     where st.SPECTABLEID=470 and st.DATAAREAID in ('company1', 'company2')
)
```

Comment: Selections on DATAAREAID and PARTITION should be applied as well.

Comment: `RecId` is unique per table which makes your delete correct (but potentially slow).

Comment: @JanB.Kjeldsen I can't find PARTITION anywhere though. I'm using AX2009 RU8.

Answer (score 0):

A cause for "red hands" can sometimes be `SpecTrans` records that point to `LedgerJournalTrans` records which no longer exists.

A job for deleting them (current company only):

```
static void RedHandDirtyVendRemove(Args _args)
{
    SpecTrans st;
    VendTrans vt;
    VendTransOpen vto;    
    LedgerJournalTrans ljt;
    while select count(RecId) from st 
        group SpecTableId
        where st.RefTableId == tableNum(VendTransOpen) &&
              st.SpecCompany == curext() &&
              st.RefCompany == curext()
        exists join vto 
        where vto.RecId == st.RefRecId 
    {
        info(strFmt('%1: %2', st.RecId, tableId2name(st.SpecTableId)));
    }
    while select st 
        where st.RefTableId == tableNum(VendTransOpen) &&
              st.SpecTableId == tableNum(LedgerJournalTrans) && 
              st.SpecCompany == curext() &&
              st.RefCompany == curext()
        join vto 
        where vto.RecId == st.RefRecId 
        join vt
        where vt.RecId == vto.RefRecId
        notExists join ljt
        where ljt.RecId == st.SpecRecId 
    {
        info(strFmt('%1: %2 %3', st.RecId, vt.Voucher, vt.AccountNum));
    }
    delete_from st 
        where st.RefTableId == tableNum(VendTransOpen) &&
              st.SpecTableId == tableNum(LedgerJournalTrans) && 
              st.SpecCompany == curext() &&
              st.RefCompany == curext()
        exists join vto 
        where vto.RecId == st.RefRecId 
        exists join vt
        where vt.RecId == vto.RefRecId
        notExists join ljt
        where ljt.RecId == st.SpecRecId;
    info(strFmt('%1', st.RowCount()));
}
```

Comment: This might be AX 2012 only. Use at your own risk.